# 301 Moved Permanently when fetch Google Webmasters

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress 3.5.1, when i am fetch Google Webmasters

```
Fetch as Google
This is how Googlebot fetched the page.
URL: http://www.drieanto.net/
Date: Friday, March 22, 2013 at 7:14:20 PM PDT
Googlebot Type: Web
Download Time (in milliseconds): 392
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: hosting
Date: Sat, 23 Mar 2013 02:14:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
X-Pingback: http://drieanto.net/xmlrpc.php
Location: http://drieanto.net/
```

how can i solve this problem.

Comment: What's the problem?  You have a 301 redirect from www.drieanto.net to driento.net ... so?

Comment: how to remove it? my website can't index google :((

Comment: You mean google isn't indexing your website?  http://goo.gl/abZ7q ... Your sitemap.xml and robots.txt looks okay ... add a line to your robots.txt -- 
Sitemap: http://www.drieanto.net/sitemap.xml -- and you're keeping up your Google Webmaster Tools.  You've added the sitemaps in Google Webmaster Tools, correct?